# MathJax で矢印上部のちょうど真ん中に文字列を配置したい

Tags: latex, mathjax

MathJax において、`\iff` の上に `\overset` で文字列を置くとやや左側に寄って表示されます。LaTeX で同じことをしたときのように文字列の中心と矢印の中心を合わせたいのですが、どのように書けば良いのでしょうか？

```html
<script type="math/tex; mode=display">% <![CDATA[
a \sim b \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} a - b \equiv 0 \pmod{p} %]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

[image: 上のスニペットを実行したときのスクリーンショットです]

※黄色くマーカーを付けた「def」が少し左に寄っています。

#### 手元の実行環境

- Windows 10
- Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試してみたところ，`\mathrel{\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}}` のように `\mathrel{}` で囲むと def の出力位置（というより `\iff` の出力位置）が次のように変わるようでした。

上：`\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}`
下：`\mathrel{\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}}`

[image: 比較]

Comment: ありがとうございます！　具体的な理由は分かりませんでしたが確かにこの方法で中心に寄せることができました。また、MathJax における `\overset` の定義などを参考にしたところ、[`\stackrel`](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/419b0a6eee7eefc0f85e47f7d4f8227ec28b8e57/unpacked/jax/input/TeX/jax.js#L825) を使うと同じように出力されました：`\stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff}`

Answer (score 0):

[@YusukeTerada さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/51739/19110)と実質的に同じことをしているのですが、[`\stackrel`](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/419b0a6eee7eefc0f85e47f7d4f8227ec28b8e57/unpacked/jax/input/TeX/jax.js#L825) を使って解決することもできるようでした。

```
\stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff}
```